# I have a simple site and want to change my font-size when the mouse is over but this code don't work.Why?

Tags: javascript, html

```
document.getElementById("change").onmouseover = function() {
  changeingFont();
};
document.getElementById("change").onmouseout = function() {
  normalFont();
};
function changeingFont() {
  document.getElementById("chnage").style.fontSize = "25px";
}
function normalFont() {
  document.getElementById("change").style.fontSize = "15px";
}
```

**For code**

> I have hyperlinks in HTML(a tag) and when i hover the text with mouse the text have to be larger.And this doesn't work...I don't know why...May someone help me ?

Comment: **It's just a typo, folks, please vote accordingly.** You have `chnage`  instead of `change` in `changeingFont`.

Comment: We need enough code to understand what is going on.  For all we know, this code is above your HTML body and the elements don't exist by the time this code executes.  Please provide a [mre]

Comment: A few notes: 1. I recommend using CSS for this (`#change:hover { font-size: 25px; }`). 2. Changing the font size/weight when the mouse is over the text tends to make for a janky user experience, as things move around just as the cursor hovers over the element. 3. If you *do* use JavaScript for this, use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) rather than assigning to `onmouseover`/`onmouseout`. 4. In the handler, you can reference the element via `this`, so you could do `changeingFont(this)` to pass it into the changing function...

Comment: ...so you don't have to look it up again in the DOM (and so you can reuse the function). 5. The word "changing" shouldn't have an `e` in it. :-) Happy coding!

Comment: In a comment on an answer below, you've said fixing the typo doesn't fix the problem. [It does if we make reasonable assumptions about where your code is](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/40roaLwg/). Look in the web console for errors, you may be trying to hook up the handlers before the element exists. More on that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element).

Comment: *"I have hyperlinks in HTML(a tag) and when i hover the text with mouse the text have to be larger."* You've used the plural, "hyperlinks," there. But you can only have `id="change"` on **one** element in the page. If you need to do this for multiple elements, use a class rather than an ID, and (again) use CSS: `.change:hover { font-size: 25px; }`.

Comment: Thanks for all but for spelling ... I just hurred :-)

Answer (score 0):

The immediate answer was a typo, but I wanted to offer a little more to help you improve. You're overriding the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` event handlers, but we could be a little nicer and use listeners:

```
const change = document.getElementById("change");
change.addEventListener("mouseover", () => changeFont());
change.addEventListener("mouseout", () => normalFont());

function changeFont() {
    change.style.fontSize = "25px";
}

function normalFont() {
    change.style.fontSize = "15px";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for understanding and helping to me:)